# return when winform's webbrowser browse set of url addresses

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I need to browse a set of url adresses (yes another web scraper..).
I want to use tasks. But I have problem returning AFTER the browser is finished.

To be sure the site is fully loaded I have to jump to `document_completed` and from there I call the Navigate method with another url.

Something like this:

```
private WebBrowser browser;
private List<string> urlsToVisit;
int urlCounter = 0;

public PageBrowser(List<string> urls) //constructor
{
    urlCounter = 0;
    urlsToVisit = urls;
    browser = new WebBrowser(); //one instance of browser for all urls
    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
}

//this I want to call from somewhere else and return true AFTER it opens all sites
public bool Run()
{
    VisitPages();
    return true;
}

private void VisitPages()
{         
    if (urlCounter < urlsToVisit.Count)
    {
        browser.Navigate(urlsToVisit[urlCounter]);               
        urlCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        browser.Dispose();
    }
}

private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath) return;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //random interval between requests
    VisitPages();
}
```

I am pretty sure, the solution is very simple but I just don't see it..

Thank you

Petr

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a `WebClient` instead of a `WebBrowser` UI component since you don't seem to need to render anything. It seems as you just want to send requests to your list of urls and return true if everything went well, and return false if any type of problem occured.

```
private async Task<bool> VisitUrls()
{
    var urls = new List<string>
    {
        "http://stackoverflow.com", 
        "http://serverfault.com/", 
        "http://superuser.com/"
    };
    var success = await BrowseUrls(urls);
    return success;
}

private async Task<bool> BrowseUrls(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var timeoutWebClient = new WebClient();
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = await timeoutWebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            if (data.Length == 0) return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Everything went well, returning true
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, thank you for your suggestion. I forgot to add, I need javascript support. Often I need inject my js function in the header and execute it, i.e. when there is a button "Load more items" and it executes some AJAX and adds more items on the page, I would like to do this programmatically.